# 0 method return values in Mac OS X packages

Tags: macos, package, swt

I'm playing around - my first SWT application.
When I package my eclipse SWT Table java application, Mac OS X 10.6.8, the method return value is 0.  If I remove the .app and execute the application executable file, it works fine.  It works fine in eclipse.  It works fine in Windows 7.  My "debug" message box always contains correct values.  If I hardcode Table clientHeight, headerHeight and itemHeight the return value is correct.

```
private int adjustItemsNEEDED(Table tTable) {
    int itemsNeeded = 0;
    int clientHeight = tTable.getClientArea().height;
    int headerHeight = tTable.getHeaderHeight();
    int itemHeight = tTable.getItemHeight();

    if (itemHeight != 0) {
        itemsNeeded = (clientHeight - headerHeight) / itemHeight;
    } else {
        itemsNeeded = 0;
    }
    messageTextBoxTop.setText("height=" + clientHeight + " header=" + headerHeight + "                item=" + itemHeight + " needed=" + itemsNeeded);
    return itemsNeeded;
}
```

my executable file:

```
#!/bin/sh
BASEDIR=`dirname $0`
exec java \
-d64 \
-XstartOnFirstThread \
-classpath $BASEDIR/org.eclipse.SWT.cocoa.macosx.x64/swt.jar:$BASEDIR \
-Djava.library.path=$BASEDIR/org.eclipse.SWT.cocoa.macosx.x64 \
MyApp
```

my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>CheckBook</string>
<key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
<string>SWTHello 1.0 for Mac OS X</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>CheckBook.icns</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>org.eclipse.swt.HelloWorldSWTApplication</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>CheckBook</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>?????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Sorry - first post - my method is called from:      shell.addListener(SWT.Activate, new Listener() { }